# find highest proportion in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x <- data.frame(sector=rep(1:5, each=2),
                subspecies=rep(c("Type A", "Type B"), 5),
                proportion= c(.2, 1-.2, .3, 1-.3, .4, 
                              1-.4, .5, 1-.5, .6, 1-.6))

x$dominance <- NA

x[,1] <- sort(x[,1])

x
   sector subspecies proportion dominance
1       1     Type A        0.2        NA
2       1     Type B        0.8        NA
3       2     Type A        0.3        NA
4       2     Type B        0.7        NA
5       3     Type A        0.4        NA
6       3     Type B        0.6        NA
7       4     Type A        0.5        NA
8       4     Type B        0.5        NA
9       5     Type A        0.6        NA
10      5     Type B        0.4        NA
```

In each sector 1-5, if Type A is the highest proportion, then I need to add 'A dominant' to the 'dominance' column, or if Type B is the highest proportion, then I need to add 'B dominant' to the 'dominance' column. If there is a tie, I need to add 'tie' to the 'dominance' column.

This should be output dataframe:

```
x$dominance <- c("B dominant", "B dominant", "B dominant", "B dominant", "B dominant", 
                 "B dominant", "tie", "tie", "A dominant", "A dominant")
x
   sector subspecies proportion  dominance
1       1     Type A        0.2 B dominant
2       1     Type B        0.8 B dominant
3       2     Type A        0.3 B dominant
4       2     Type B        0.7 B dominant
5       3     Type A        0.4 B dominant
6       3     Type B        0.6 B dominant
7       4     Type A        0.5        tie
8       4     Type B        0.5        tie
9       5     Type A        0.6 A dominant
10      5     Type B        0.4 A dominant
```

Comment: Thansk @Josh for taking the time to hand edit all the data and answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution

```
compare <- function(x) {
  ## return subspecies of max proportion
  res <- x[which(x$proportion == max(x$proportion)), "subspecies"]
  if(length(res) > 1L) { ## if tied length(res) == 2
    out <- "Tie"
  } else { ## Simple string replacement
    out <- paste(sub("Type ", "", res), "Dominant")
    ## or you could use
    #out <- if(res == "Type A") {"A Dominant"} else {"B Dominant")}
  }
  out
}

x$dominance <- unsplit(lapply(split(x, x$sector), compare), x$sector)

> x
   sector subspecies proportion  dominance
1       1     Type A        0.2 B Dominant
2       1     Type B        0.8 B Dominant
3       2     Type A        0.3 B Dominant
4       2     Type B        0.7 B Dominant
5       3     Type A        0.4 B Dominant
6       3     Type B        0.6 B Dominant
7       4     Type A        0.5        Tie
8       4     Type B        0.5        Tie
9       5     Type A        0.6 A Dominant
10      5     Type B        0.4 A Dominant
```

Comment: @Frank Ok, `compare` seems free.

Answer (score 4):

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(x)

 DT[, dominance := {p.a <- proportion[subspecies =="Type A"]
                    p.b <- proportion[subspecies =="Type B"] 
                   if (p.a > p.b) "A dominant" else if (p.b > p.a) "B dominant" else "tie"}
                  , by=sector]


    sector subspecies proportion  dominance
 1:      1     Type A        0.2 B dominant
 2:      1     Type B        0.8 B dominant
 3:      2     Type A        0.3 B dominant
 4:      2     Type B        0.7 B dominant
 5:      3     Type A        0.4 B dominant
 6:      3     Type B        0.6 B dominant
 7:      4     Type A        0.5        tie
 8:      4     Type B        0.5        tie
 9:      5     Type A        0.6 A dominant
10:      5     Type B        0.4 A dominant
```

Comment: That's back to front isn't it? In sector 1, A is 0.2 and B is 0.6 so it should be "B dominant", yes?

Comment: thanks @GavinSimpson.  That was a sloppy mistake on my part (I copied and pasted the text `A dominant` the same for both parts of the `if` clase).  Edited and corrected.

Comment: Hi all, it doesn't look any of those dataframes are what I'm after - see the dataframes I've added to opening post

Comment: @luciano Well if you change the input data **after** we answered is it any surprise they don't match?!

Comment: @GavinSimpson -- There was a mis-match between what the OP displayed and the code he gave for making `x`. I'm making necessary fixes.

Comment: @luciano Sorry for attributing the change to you. We did use the code you supplied so the by-hand output you gave was wrong for the example data you created. Josh has been busy fixing things.

Comment: I didn't change code that generated the dataframe, I just printed the dataframes

Comment: @luciano -- No, the four of us weren't all wrong ;) The code you had supplied produced a `sector` column that read `c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)` instead of what you had displayed, which reads `c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5)`. In any case, I've fixed it now by adding `each=2` to your call to `rep()`.

Comment: Does `x[,1] <- sort(x[,1])` not remove need for `each=2`? This was in original post. Anyway, thanks all, amazing response as usual.

Answer (score 2):

with base R:

```
do.call(rbind,
    by(x, x$sector, 
       FUN=function(sec) 
           transform(sec, 
                     dominance=if (anyDuplicated(proportion)) 'tie' 
                               else subspecies[which.max(proportion)]))

)
#      sector subspecies proportion dominance
# 1.1       1     Type A        0.2    Type B
# 1.2       1     Type B        0.8    Type B
# 2.3       2     Type A        0.3    Type B
# 2.4       2     Type B        0.7    Type B
# 3.5       3     Type A        0.4    Type B
# 3.6       3     Type B        0.6    Type B
# 4.7       4     Type A        0.5       tie
# 4.8       4     Type B        0.5       tie
# 5.9       5     Type A        0.6    Type A
# 5.10      5     Type B        0.4    Type A
```

You can break it into two parts, if doing so improves readability.

```
f <- function(sec) 
    transform(sec, dominance=if (anyDuplicated(proportion)) 'tie' 
                             else subspecies[which.max(proportion)]))
do.call(rbind, by(x, x$sector, f))
```